# Definition of bias for f-hat: Why do we take the expected value?

Tags: bias

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias.E2.80.93variance_decomposition_of_squared_error):

$$
Bias(\hat{f}(x))^2 = E[f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]]^2
$$

$\hat{f}$ is our estimate of $f$, and the expectation ranges over different choices of the training set.

The same page [also states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Derivation):

$$
Bias(\hat{f}(x))^2 = E[(f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)])^2]
$$

Subbing the first equation into the second:

$$
E[f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]]^2 = E[(f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)])^2]
$$

I want to understand why this is true, since I know that it isn't generally true that $E[expression]^2$ = $E[expression^2]$.

As I understand it, the expected values of $f(x)$ and $E[\hat{f}(x)]$ are $f(x)$ and $E[\hat{f}(x)]$ respectively; neither value is altered by taking a different choice of training set, since $f(x)$ is the actual value (and so has nothing to do with the training data), and $E[\hat{f}(x)]$ is effectively a constant, being an expected value taken across all the training data already. Please correct me if I am wrong so far!

Based on that, I take it that:

$$
E[f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]] \equiv f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]
$$

...since the outer $E[\space]$ operator in the LHS has no effect on its contents.

If so, why do we use the outer $E[\space]$ operator in our definition of bias? What situations require it?

Comment: That second eq you have for the bias isn't quite right. That's the second moment for a centered random quantity aka the variance. The two are related through the decomposition of the MSE into bias and variance you linked to.

Comment: @NickThieme How is the second equation a variance? The true function is $f(x)$ and so it doesn't have a variance (it's not random). The estimated function is $\hat{f}(x)$ and has a variance, but it's not the second equation mentioned in the post. The variance of $\hat{f}(x)$ is $$\textrm{Var}\left[\hat{f}(x)\right]=\textrm{E}\left[\left(\hat{f}(x)-\textrm{E}\left(\hat{f}(x)\right)\right)^2\right]$$

Comment: @StatsNoob I don't see the second equation on the Wikipedia page. Instead I see $$\textrm{Bias}[\hat{f}]^2=(f-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}])^2$$

Comment: As you have it written, it's not. But since your link goes directly to the variance, and I couldn't find the claim you make on that page (which I've never seen), I figured it was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. Coincidentally, the derivation on the Wikipedia page I referenced was updated after I read it - see the old revision here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff&oldid=641592779#Derivation

Comment: (Oops, hit Enter too early.)
The current revision does now indeed say that 
$$
Bias[\hat{f}(x)]^2 = (f - E[\hat{f}(x)])^2
$$
(This is also what I reached in my own derivation.)

Was I correct in saying, then, that $E[f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]] \equiv f(x) - E[\hat{f}(x)]$?